# Force output of + operator to be the same as its input in a function?

Tags: function, generics, types, rust, addition

I have a function `test` that calculates the sum of two variables of type `N`, returning `N`. How can I specify `N::Output` type must be `N`?

```
use std::ops::Add;

fn test<N: Add>(num_a: N, num_b: N) -> N {
    num_a + num_b
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", test(5, 7));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=77aa319219261ce7d4453ab8907dfa2f&version=stable)

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:5
  |
3 | fn test<N: Add>(num_a: N, num_b: N) -> N {
  |                                        - expected `N` because of return type
4 |     num_a + num_b
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected type parameter, found associated type
  |
  = note: expected type `N`
             found type `<N as std::ops::Add>::Output`
```

Comment: `N: Add<Output = N>`